# Repeated transaction hashes

Tags: transactions

I have used following code to grab transaction hash every time a transfer event is triggered and store them in an array.

```
contarct1=web3.eth.contract(ABiDefination).at(address);
var arr=[];
var i=0;
function Eventt(){
     contract1.Transfer(function(error,result){
          if(!error){
               arr[i]=result.transactionHash;
               console.log(i);
               console.log(arr[i]);
               document.getElementById('txhash1').innerText="array  is "+ arr ;
               i=i+1;
          }
      })
}
```

Here `Transfer` is the event which is declared  in my contract as `event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`.

Now in my code I am calling this `Eventt()` inside `transfer(..)` function (and inside transfer(..) `Transfer` event is fired). I am also able to get transaction hashes. 
But the issue is when I call `transfer(..)` function for first time, I get a transaction hash which is corresponding to that transaction, but the second time I call `transfer(..)` function, I get 3 elements inside my array,first is for the first transaction and 2nd and 3rd are same. And this keeps on going, for third time I get 6 elements inside my array. 
I am unable to track why I am getting repeated values. Any solutions, or any alternate way to capture transaction hashes?

I also not sure

1. whether the line  `contract1.Transfer(function(error,result){})` watches changes in event or anything else?
2. and what is meaning of indexed in line `event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`

Comment: Are you using this against TestRPC?

Comment: Yes, I am using this against private TestNet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Every time you call `Eventt()` you add a listener to `contract1.Transfer()`. So after 2 times, you have 2 listeners, with the second one starting at a later block. And because your `arr=[]` is global, both listeners add to the same array. This explains why you get `[tx1, tx2, tx2]`. After 3 times, you of course get `[tx1, tx2, tx2, tx3, tx3, tx3]`.

What you need to do is call `Eventt()` once only on page load.

And if ever you need to stop, look at [`.stopWatching()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#returns-47)

2. `indexed` means that you will be able to query per values of this field for all instance of this event. Look at [`.filter()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter).